# android facebook sdk 4.2 open graph stories and maps

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share open graph stories and locations for a fitness course using facebook android sdk version 4.2,

I would like to have something like this:

https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t39.2178-6/851557_504281972964839_1538874606_n.png

but the map does not show up

basically my code look like this:

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "fitness.course")
    .putString("og:title", "Sample Course")
    .putString("og:description", "This is a sample course.")
    .putInt("fitness:duration:value", 100)
    .putString("fitness:duration:units", "s")
    .putInt("fitness:distance:value", 12)
    .putString("fitness:distance:units", "km")
    .putInt("fitness:speed:value", 5)
    .putString("fitness:speed:units", "m/s");

    ArrayList<ShareOpenGraphObject> metrics = new ArrayList<ShareOpenGraphObject>();
    ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder metric1 = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();
    String timestamp1 = dateFormat.format(new Date(realDateTime1));
    metric1.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:latitude", latitude1);
    metric1.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:longitude",longitude1);
    metric1.putString("fitness:metrics:timestamp",timestamp1);
    metrics.add(metric1.build());
    ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder metric2 = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder();
    String timestamp2 = dateFormat.format(new Date(realDateTime2));
    metric2.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:latitude", latitude2);
    metric2.putDouble("fitness:metrics:location:longitude",longitude2);
    metric2.putString("fitness:metrics:timestamp",timestamp2);
    metrics.add(metric2.build());

    .....

    object.putObjectArrayList("fitness:metrics", metrics);

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
     .setActionType("fitness.runs")
     .putObject("fitness:course", object.build())
     .putString("fitness:start_time", startTime)
     .putString("fitness:end_time", endTime)
     .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
     .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
     .setAction(action)
     .build();
```

I did several tries without success, for example if I don't use the metrics array showed above and I put fitness:metrics:location:* directly on the original object builder the map is shown with a single location. Hints?

Comment: the problem was reported to the facebook bug tracker. This is a bug in facebook android sdk  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1444106165910032

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, in my case I had a web backend that host the fitness course and I solved it by setting in the ShareOpenGrapAction the url of the fitness course.

In the web backend the fitness course is created using the reference stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness

In the app

```
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
        .setActionType("fitness.runs")
        .putString("fitness:course", url)
        .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
        .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
        .setAction(action)
        .build();
```

Than call the show

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: would you share what the content in the url is? I tried this but I get 
Object at URL ... has og:type of 'website'. The property 'course' requires an object of og:type 'fitness.course'.  [extra]: